# set value of structs in xaml with staticresource

Tags: wpf, xaml

For example:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
<sys:String x:Key="Str1">Hello World</sys:String>
<sys:Int32 x:Key="Int1">1</sys:Int32>
```

Is it now possible to replace the inner parts with StaticResources, something like:

```
<sys:String x:Key="Str1">{StaticResource StrRes}</sys:String>
<sys:Int32 x:Key="Int1">{StaticResource IntRes}</sys:Int32>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so. The values that you assign to the immutable structs defined in the XAML markup must be compile-time constants.

But why would you need this anyway? What's the point of defining another XAML resource with the exact same value as an already existing resource? Then you might as well use/reference the original resource directly.

Maybe you want to use your own custom "proxy" dependency object with a string property:

```
public class MyString : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TheStringProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("TheString", typeof(string), typeof(MyString));

    public string TheString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TheStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TheStringProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

---

```
<sys:String x:Key="Str1">Hello World</sys:String>
<local:MyString x:Key="StrRes" TheString="{StaticResource Str1}" />
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TheString, Source={StaticResource StrRes}}" />
```